# How to continuously Increment & Decrement with (+1) & (-1) in iOS calculator without the Button "="

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8.1

First sorry for my poor English.

I am creating a basic iOS calculator for iPhone 6, since I am a beginner for iPhone development.
Everything is working fine, addition, subtraction etc. 
Now I want to make this calculator app for black jack card counting.

But my question is:
Q) Is it possible to continuously calculate add +1 to the value without the "=" button? That is I want to continuously add +1 when I press (Low +1) button and subtract -1 when I press (High -1) button?

Please give me some suggestion. And Sorry again for my poor English.

Comment: You can use increment operators

Comment: @channi Do I need to predefine the value in the button?

Comment: I have not played blackjack till now sorry for that, but yes you can predefine those values as per the requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one suggestion would be to provide a `up` and `down` button (or `increment` and `decrement` or whatever else you might call them) which simply added or subtracted one from the current display value.

Depending on how your code is structured, this could be as simple as something like:

```
case INCR_BTN:
    setDisplay (getDisplay() + 1);
    break;
case DECR_BTN:
    setDisplay (getDisplay() - 1);
    break;
```

(in C, but similar enough to ObjC that it'll help out).

But keep in mind I don't think many of the casinos are going to let you sit at their Blackjack tables messing about with your iPhone :-) The best card counters are the ones that do it in their head but, even then, if you seem to be winning too much, they'll start cutting the shoe earlier to remove any advantage counting may give you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am a very beginner in programming, I will check what is increment and decrement. Can you provide me an example? Because I follow all youtube tutorials

Comment: there are no casinos in my country, so I cannot mess around.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I will look towards it.Thank you. But 1 more question, whenever I try to refresh, my program breaks or stop working

Comment: @bleach64, you should ask a _different_ question on why that happens since it's not really related to _this_ question. That's the way SO works. Just be sure to include a lot of detail when you ask it.

Comment: I am sorry for not that informative, next time I will sure to put a lot of details, Thanks again for the information SIR